# How to change element color vector drawable?

Tags: android, kotlin, colors

I imported svg image to android studio, which is similar to this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?reload=9&v=n0e7z9anHHc.

I would like to create an smooth change color,  because I'm a beginner, I don't know how from the code level I can set green color e.g Animating this the transition through the gradient within 3 seconds. How can I smooth change the color of a vector graphic element?

Comment: Can you share which part of the video are you looking to achieve?

Comment: At the very beginning film of the shown the button I  imported to Android Studio  is shown. The default is red, but I'd like to create a smooth (animated) transition to green.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Shapeshifter (https://shapeshifter.design/)to make an animated vector drawable from one colour to another. 
Then On click you can animate it

```
(someImageView.drawable as AnimatedVectorDrawable).start()
```

For more details check this :

https://sourcediving.com/android-recipes-the-easy-path-to-animated-icons-878bffcb0920

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I would like to set other colors on the button also. I would like to create a function in which I pass a value in the range 0-100, where these values ​​correspond to the gradient (red-yellow-green). Depending on the value provided, the button will change smoothly to a given color starting from red.